# vsftp doesn't respect chmod setting when uploading outside my local network

Tags: permissions, chmod, sftp, vsftpd

Yo! I've a ftp server on my linux machine and I've set the following rules: I keep group and owner and chmod it to 775. When I use it at home (192.168.x.x) it's ok, files keep their group and user owner and chmod@775, but when I use it outside (at work for example, I use filezilla portable client), ftp connexion (that I use at home) fails and I need to use sftp, and uploaded files are with the good group and owner but with 755 permissions (the server is configured to chmod files to 775)...And I can't create directories (but of course it works at home, server configured to allow dir creation).

vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=myftp.

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
nopriv_user=publichttp
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list #empty file
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list

anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
file_open_mode=0777
```

thanks to anyone who have a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you overlooked this (from [vsftpd.conf(5)](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)):

> **`anon_umask`**
>   The value that the umask for file creation is set to for anonymous users. NOTE! If you want to specify octal values, remember the "0" prefix otherwise the value will be treated as a base 10 integer!

```
Default: 077
```

Comment: asked a friend to try at his home, seems to work, thanks